# DSE Search 5.1 broken compatibility on spatial searches

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

Recently I upgraded from DSE 5.0 to 5.1 and I was glad to see the Solr upgrade to 6.0 until I realised that our query syntax to do some spatial searches were broken (via JTS).

Under DSE Search 5.1, this query is broken:

```
coords:"Intersects(Circle(10 10 d=2))"
```

Solr responds:

> "msg": "Unknown Shape definition [Circle(10 10 d=2)]",

however, this statement worked on all the previous versions.

It seems that **Circle** spatial command is no longer available. Can anybody say whether Circle is no longer supported?.

Comment: Did you try geofilt? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search

Comment: I found that a similar result can be achieved not using JTS at all.  http://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/search/queriesGeoSpatial.html  coords:"Intersects(BUFFER(POINT(10 10),2) gets a similar result.

Comment: thank you @phact. Indeed. I think Solr guys try to get rid of the JTS api in somehow. geofilt seems to work pretty well too but I rather prefer the DSE syntax described on [link](http://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/search/queriesGeoSpatial.html) It's more intuitive for our environment.